# .NET Transforms is it possible to change PropertyGroup in csproj files?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, transform

This way be a silly question.

I've got a web app with many configurations. For simplicity let's say Qa and Local.

In each of my projects there's a PropertyGroup for each of the configurations to define settings when w configuration is selected.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Qa|AnyCPU'">
<DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/</DeployIisAppPath>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
<IncludeIisSettings>false</IncludeIisSettings>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
```

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Local|AnyCPU'">
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

So basically Qa is configured to be as optimized as possible, disabling debugging, TRACE. Which makes sense for when I deploy.
The problem comes when we I need to debug Qa. I change the configuration to Qa and change my web.config to point to the Qa configuration. This way VS builds bin path for Qa with the connections strings used to connect to Qa. The side effect of this is it disables debug on All of my projects and I have to turn them all back on temporarily to get breakpoints into what I need. That sucks, and I want ot change it.

Is it possible to just leave Debug enabled on all these projects configs then have some kind of tool that reverses Debug out when it's time to deploy? My first thought was adding a transform to modify this but transforms can't change csproj file right? Is there some other tool out there that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project configuration already is a good tool to determine when to use which settings. Project configuration names do not have to be in 1-to-1 relation to target environments - you can have more (or less).

So instead of changing debugging settings for "QA" in one configuration settings back and forth, you could have prepared configurations like:

- local
- QA debugging
- QA optimized

.. or however many different configurations you need.

By default your CI toolset could be set up to deploy to QA environment using the configuration "QA optimized". If you run into a hard-to-track problem and need to debug it remotely, you can build and deploy instead using the "QA with debugging" configuration.

Comment: True but that would add clutter. It might be the best thing to do in this situation.